# Use fill handle in Excel to create monthly summaries

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with data laid out in the following fashion:

```
01/01/19 data1 data2
02/01/19 data1 data2
...
29/01/19 data1 data2
30/01/19 data1 data2 avg1 avg2
```

I wish to summarise and analyse the data at the end of each month in a way that allows me to extend the spreadsheet simply by dragging the fill handle. This would be easy to do if I wanted weekly averages, for instance as Excel would just paste the formula producing the average on every seventh row. Months, however, vary in length so I'm unsure how to make this happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use EOMONTH to calculate if the date in the current row is the last of the month. If so, you can use AverageIFS to calculate the average. If your dates are in column A and the values to be averaged are in column B, first row has headers, start in C2 with this formula and copy down.

```
=if(eomonth(A2,0)=A2,averageIFS(B:B,A:A,"<="&eomonth(A2,0),A:A,">"&eomonth(A2,-1)),"")
```